# Don't have the correct permission for /var/www/html

Tags: whonix

I'm able to write changes in the home directory, but when it comes to the /var/www/html folder, it's not allowing me to make any changes or create new files or folders. I can view the folders and files as well.

I have tried to add my username to the group that it belongs to, but I get the message that I don't even have the correct permissions to change that inside the terminal. Please suggest what I should do to correct this. Thanks.

This is inside Whonix if that helps.

Comment: You may need to logout and back in... or type `$ newgrp <group you added yourself to>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me show my current setting, that may help you to to give correct permission and group owner to files and directory.

This my current chown and chmod for **/var/www/**

```
$ ls -l /var/www/
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Jan  4 16:25 cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x. 8 root root 4096 Mar  4 08:54 html
```

And for inside **/html/**

```
$ ls -l /var/www/html/
drwxr-xr-x.  3 rob rob 4096 Nov  4 11:41 adminer
drwxr-xr-x.  8 rob rob 4096 Oct  5  2015 DVWA-1.9
drwxr-xr-x. 11 rob rob 4096 Dec 10 14:24 eDokumen
```

I alway use this recursive command. PHP files are run under the user of the website instead of the Apache user and globally reset all files (user,group,file and directory):

```
$ sudo chown -R user:group *
$ sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
$ sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

* Note : Replace the user and group label with you own setting